# What is the difference between sing for / sing to me?

Tags: difference

Currently i am reading a book called 'Lick' by Kylie Scott

I came across the above phrases on pg 89 - 90 where the lead character asks this question or uses expression in the following ways - that are

1. Will you sing for me ?
2. Did you sing to me that night ?
3. Please sing me a song ?

I was wondering what's the difference in those.

Comment: “Did you sing to me that night” could mean, “Although you were singing for a larger audience, was your song addressed especially to me? Was I the ‘you’ of the song?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little difference.

In the case of *sing for*, the singer may simply be singing aloud; the singing is not necessarily directed at the listener, it just fills the environment.

In the case of *sing to*, the singer is singing directly at the listener.